# Modify the optional argument of sectioning commands to pass key val lists

Tags: sectioning, pgfkeys, l3keys

Standard classes have sectioning commands with an optional first argument, that can contain an alt title to be used in the table of contents and running heads. If one needs to use a keyval interface without changing the user API, the keys can be passed after it. The code below, attempts to detect if there is a first argument with a short title and or keys. My question is, how can this be improved and or any other suggestions. I detect the presence of key(s) by the presence of an `=` symbol. This fails if the keys have the form of styles in pgfkeys or like |10pt| in normal keys. I could ask the user to mark the end of a short title with a signal such as `>>` but prefer not to, so older documents can be processed without changes. Another alternative is to add a dummy key, so that the user input is always to the left. Any other ideas?

```
\documentclass{book}
% Needed if using g-specifier
\usepackage{xparse}
% use pgfkeys for key-val lists
\usepackage{pgfkeys,xcolor}
% create set-keys macro with family /phd
\newcommand\cxset{\pgfqkeys{/phd/.is family}}
% define some keys
\cxset{keya/.store in=\AAA,
       keyb/.store in = \BBB,
       keyc/.store in = \CCC}
% give some values to the keys       
\cxset{keya = AAA,
       keyb = BBB,
       keyc = CCC}
% set a style so we can append to and modify later on
\cxset{defaults/.style ={keya = AAA,
                         keyb = BBB,
                         keyc = CCC }    
}
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \short_title_tl
\tl_new:N  \long_title_tl
\tl_new:N \saved_keys_tl
\tl_new:N \short_or_long_title_tl
% initialize to error
\tl_set:Nn\short_or_long_title_tl{\ERROR}
% 
\NewDocumentCommand\altorkeys{ s o +m }
  {  
    \IfValueTF{#2}
      {  % need 2 lists one for tail another
         % one for original input
         \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{#2}
            \clist_gpop:NN\l_tmpa_clist\l_tmpa_tl
          % save unpopped  
          \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpb_clist{#2}
          
         % check first item for = as a signal we have keys  
         % alt signal count items might fail?
          \tl_if_in:NnTF\l_tmpa_tl{=}
            {
              %\clist_push:NV \l_tmpa_clist\l_tmpa_tl 
              \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpb_clist {\appendstyle{##1}}   
              \tl_set:Nn\short_or_long_title_tl{#3}
              \tl_set_eq:NN \saved_keys_tl\l_tmpb_clist    
            }

            { %case we have short title
              \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\appendstyle{##1}}   
              \tl_set_eq:NN \short_title_tl\l_tmpa_tl
              \tl_set_eq:NN\short_or_long_title_tl\l_tmpa_tl      
            }

         
          
          % At this point we can end wit an empty clist as we popped 
          % the first item and it only had one item
          \clist_if_empty:NT\l_tmpa_clist
          {
           \clist_push:NV \l_tmpa_clist\l_tmpa_tl
           \tl_set_eq:NN\short_or_long_title_tl\l_tmpa_tl
            
          }
 
      }
    
    % case empty options
    { 

      \tl_set:Nn\short_or_long_title_tl{#3}

    } 
    
    % case star
    \IfBooleanT#1
      {
       \tl_set:Nn \short_or_long_title_tl{#3}
      }  
      
  % print title  
    
    %\section[\short_or_long_title_tl]{#3}
  }

\def\appendstyle#1{
 \cxset{defaults}
 \cxset{ defaults/.append~style={#1}}
 \cxset{ defaults}
}


\NewDocumentCommand\mocktest{ }
   {   
          
       \altorkeys[short mock]{Long mock title}
       \section[\short_or_long_title_tl]{\short_or_long_title_tl}

       \altorkeys[short mock, keya=a,keyb=b, keyc=c]{Long mock title with short and keys}
       \section[\short_or_long_title_tl]{\short_or_long_title_tl}

       \altorkeys[keya=a,keyb=b]{Long mock title with  keys}
       \section[\short_or_long_title_tl]{\short_or_long_title_tl}

       \altorkeys{Long mock title,nostar, nooptions, noshort }
       \section{\short_or_long_title_tl}

       \altorkeys*[short*]{Long mock title,star, nooptions, short *}
       \section*{\short_or_long_title_tl}
         This~should~not~be~in~the~contents\par   
         ========Keys Test ==================\par   
         Keys must~show a,b,c\par
         \AAA\par
         \BBB\par
         \CCC

   }


\ExplSyntaxOff



\mocktest

\section*[short]{Vanilla LaTeX section star with empty options}

\section{}
This is a section in Vanilla LaTeX with empty title
\end{document}
```

Comment: we added the `=`  key handler for exactly this reason it standardises a heuristic for checking if an option is a keyval list or a "classic" string for direct use see `texdoc usrguide `   2.9 Auto-converting to key–value format

Comment: Thanks David, I remember I saw this somewhere in the announcements, just couldn't find it. I also notice that xparse exists both as a package as well as the code has been incorporated in the source, but without loading the package I cannot use the g-specifier. Any eplanation for this?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides We moved the functionality we were happy with to the kernel, and left the bits we decided were less-than-ideal experiments in `xparse`. The `g`-type argument was one of the latter things: it will remain available for ever, just requires that you load `xparse` explicitly.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides `g`-type arguments don't fit into the standard LaTeX model, which is why we did not move that to the kernel

Comment: For PGFKeys: This should be `\pgfqkeys{/phd}`, otherwise all your keys are `/phd/.is family/keya` and so one. I would use two approaches to this: Firstly, test if your optional argument is a valid key in your name space, this could even handle a proper `=` even if it just contains a short title (which just happen to have a `=`) in it. Secondly, you can use `.unknown/.code` in your namespace to handle unknown keys and treat them as short titles. Problem: PGFKeys throughs the key name directly into a `\csname` or `\ifcsname` rather which will lead to problems with non-expandable “keys”.

Comment: One thing in favour of the new mech in the kernel: if you have `\foo[{bar = baz}]{...}`, you'll strip the braces and 'see' a `=` if you just do the normal processing, but the `={..}` `ltcmd` mechanism checks for braces _first_ so can cope with this.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, I have some older stuff where I used it, but best I think when I get a chance is to modify the code. If you have the chance can you please add a small minimal for a sample command, using `s o +m`?  demonstrating how to extract the short title and the keys? I read the usrguide? Examples are not very clear to me.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for the comments. Thanks for catching the error on the family and the suggestion to use the .unknown  handler, I guess pretty much like PGF handles color?

Comment: Indeed, TikZ tries: `/pgf/<unknown key>`? Name of color? Color spec with `!`? Arrow spec (i.e. `-`)? Shape? You could just test (either explicitly or via `.unknown`) whether `short mock` is a key name (if not it's your short title). But we have to deal with unexpandable content (→ `\detokenize` patch for PGFKeys), equal sign (spaces around it will be removed unless protected), commas (need to protected, of course) and slashes (they absolutely need to be handled outside of PGFKeys). `Slash/Test` will leed to the key `/phd/Slash/Test` which will try to find `Test` in `/phd/Slash`.

Comment: Similar to Koma-Script I'd restrict the input syntax. Or use two alternatives for your command: only kv (with `[]`) or only the title (with `{}). Otherwise, you will have to do a lot of parsing on your own (as your code) but why use PGFKeys then? I like to use it but it simply was not made for this.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, I am using pgfkeys as I have 100s keys and many custom handlers defined in the code I want to use, mostly generated programmatically. It also has a much cleaner interface than l3 keys. If I ask the user to put a marker after the short title say `>` like `[short title>key1,key2,key3...] `  then parsing is a breeze.